# Copying a software RAID 1 to a normal SATA II disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-utility

I need to copy my software RAID 0 (GA-P55-UD5, intel controller) to a normal SATA II disk. I've tried Clonezilla but it won't recognize my RAID volume; just the single disks that are part of it.

How can I solve the problem and keep my Windows 7 (now sitting on the RAID 0 volume) bootable even after the data transfer on the new disk?

Free solutions are welcome but if there are none, paid ones are too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use drive snapshot.

It can copy your entire partitions on a live system. It's your cure.
[Drive Snapshot](http://www.drivesnapshot.de/en/)

Comment: I'm lovin'it! :D

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use a program like Acronis true image home. I have had great luck with that and it's only $30. You should be able to use the demo to make a backup, and if it recognizes the raid, purchase it. Also a great program for backups once you are squared away.

You can either use the boot cd and clone from the raid to the new disk, or install the software and make a bare metal backup with the OS running.

Comment: That would be much simpler if the RAID config is recognised - fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - interesting challenge! - off the top of my head...

- Use [VMWare Convertor](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) to create a virtualised copy of the machine that you could then run in VirtualBox of with VMWare Player or VMware ESXi
- Fire up the Virtualised copy to confirm it runs.
- Boot the virtualised machine off a Clonezilla/[Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php) live CD or USB stick and clone the virtual machine disk to the new target hard disk attached to the VM via a USB caddy.
- Take the disk out of the USB caddy and fit it as the main boot disk for the PC.
- Fire up and see what happens!

If you can't get the target disk to run off a USB port in the virtualised world, clone the virtual machine disk to an image file and then boot the underlying PC straight into Clonezilla/parted magic (no virtualisation involved) and restore the cloned image to the USB attached disk.

Love to know if this actually works + comments from anyone else about this or other methods.

Comment: I think it should be definitely working but with a nasty impact on my hardware, right?
It's a silly gaming machine and therefore all video and audio drivers and tweaks should be kept...
Anyhow it's a good idea, I'll see if I can find anything better and then try it :) thanks

Comment: Ah, but when done, the freshly cloned disk can be hooked to the machine as its main disk and all the virtualisation stuff will be gone - I'll point that out in my answer.